# How do I solve this code signing error when building iOS app?

Tags: ios

```
CopySwiftLibs /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testtt-crjmujkhpfhokjabtvhimrwqyhod/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/testtt.app (in target: testtt)
    cd /Users/admin/Desktop/desktop/projects/testtt
    export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
    export DEVELOPER_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    export SDKROOT=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.1.sdk
    builtin-swiftStdLibTool --copy --verbose --sign 24177DC0179155D95B9619ABA2C4EEE5017D157F --scan-executable /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testtt-crjmujkhpfhokjabtvhimrwqyhod/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/testtt.app/testtt --scan-folder /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testtt-crjmujkhpfhokjabtvhimrwqyhod/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/testtt.app/Frameworks --scan-folder /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testtt-crjmujkhpfhokjabtvhimrwqyhod/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/testtt.app/PlugIns --platform iphoneos --toolchain /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain --destination /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testtt-crjmujkhpfhokjabtvhimrwqyhod/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/testtt.app/Frameworks --strip-bitcode --resource-destination /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testtt-crjmujkhpfhokjabtvhimrwqyhod/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/testtt.app --resource-library libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib --strip-bitcode-tool /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip --emit-dependency-info /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testtt-crjmujkhpfhokjabtvhimrwqyhod/Build/Intermediates.noindex/testtt.build/Debug-iphoneos/testtt.build/SwiftStdLibToolInputDependencies.dep

Requested Swift ABI version based on scanned binaries: 6
libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib is up to date at /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testtt-crjmujkhpfhokjabtvhimrwqyhod/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/testtt.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib
libswiftCoreImage.dylib is up to date at /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testtt-crjmujkhpfhokjabtvhimrwqyhod/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/testtt.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreImage.dylib
libswiftFoundation.dylib is up to date at /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testtt-crjmujkhpfhokjabtvhimrwqyhod/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/testtt.app/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib
libswiftDarwin.dylib is up to date at /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testtt-crjmujkhpfhokjabtvhimrwqyhod/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/testtt.app/Frameworks/libswiftDarwin.dylib
libswiftUIKit.dylib is up to date at /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testtt-crjmujkhpfhokjabtvhimrwqyhod/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/testtt.app/Frameworks/libswiftUIKit.dylib
libswiftos.dylib is up to date at /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testtt-crjmujkhpfhokjabtvhimrwqyhod/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/testtt.app/Frameworks/libswiftos.dylib
libswiftObjectiveC.dylib is up to date at /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testtt-crjmujkhpfhokjabtvhimrwqyhod/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/testtt.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib
libswiftQuartzCore.dylib is up to date at /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testtt-crjmujkhpfhokjabtvhimrwqyhod/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/testtt.app/Frameworks/libswiftQuartzCore.dylib
libswiftCoreFoundation.dylib is up to date at /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testtt-crjmujkhpfhokjabtvhimrwqyhod/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/testtt.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreFoundation.dylib
libswiftDispatch.dylib is up to date at /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testtt-crjmujkhpfhokjabtvhimrwqyhod/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/testtt.app/Frameworks/libswiftDispatch.dylib
libswiftCore.dylib is up to date at /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testtt-crjmujkhpfhokjabtvhimrwqyhod/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/testtt.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
libswiftMetal.dylib is up to date at /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testtt-crjmujkhpfhokjabtvhimrwqyhod/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/testtt.app/Frameworks/libswiftMetal.dylib
libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib is up to date at /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testtt-crjmujkhpfhokjabtvhimrwqyhod/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/testtt.app/libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib
Probing signature of /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testtt-crjmujkhpfhokjabtvhimrwqyhod/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/testtt.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib
/usr/bin/codesign -r- --display /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testtt-crjmujkhpfhokjabtvhimrwqyhod/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/testtt.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib
/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testtt-crjmujkhpfhokjabtvhimrwqyhod/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/testtt.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib: code object is not signed at all

Codesigning /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testtt-crjmujkhpfhokjabtvhimrwqyhod/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/testtt.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign 24177DC0179155D95B9619ABA2C4EEE5017D157F --verbose /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testtt-crjmujkhpfhokjabtvhimrwqyhod/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/testtt.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib
/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testtt-crjmujkhpfhokjabtvhimrwqyhod/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/testtt.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib: errSecInternalComponent

error: Failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: What caused this error? We are not magicians to know everything. Please tell us what was your purpose, what did you try

Comment: Please [search on the error](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bios%5D+codesigning+failed+with+exit+code+1) before posting.

Answer (score -2):

You must be in Apple's paid developer program to run apps on a physical device. Upgrade to the developer license and re-load your certificate.